# PHPで，入力された電話番号等の文字列のハイフンを除去するようなフィルタをかける

Tags: php, form

### 問題の要約

PHPで，フォームから入力された電話番号の形式が NNN-NNNN-NNNN であったときに（エラーで弾くのではなく）内部で処理して NNNNNNNNNNN という数値に変換する処理を書きたいと思っています．

### これまでに試したこと

PHPのドキュメントによると，PHPには `filter_var` という，入力された値をフィルタリングする関数があります．フィルタリングには大きく分けて `VALIDATE` から始まる検証フィルタと，`SANITIZE` から始まる除去フィルタがあります．

今回やりたいことはハイフンの除去なので除去フィルタで実行できるものと期待されますが，しかし用意されたフィルタの中に「数字以外をすべて除去する」というものがありません．

ハイフン記号がマイナス記号と同じなので，「数字、プラス記号、マイナス記号 以外のすべての文字を取り除く」というようなフィルタでは生き残ってしまいます．

### まとめ

どのようにすれば，数値に交じっているハイフン記号を取り除けるでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str_replace` 関数を用いて文字列の中のハイフンを検索し，空文字列で置換すれば期待した動作になるはずです．

Comment: 空白文字ではなくて空文字（要するに削除）のほうが適切そう。あとよくありそうな入力としては 0120(xxx)yyyyy のように括弧とか、いわゆる全角で入力された場合に半角にするなどの変換もあるとUXが増しそうです。ローマ数字の変換（ V を 5 など）とかの意外な副作用がどこまで許されるかなども検討のうちに入れとくと吉。

Comment: 空文字列に修正しました．